# How to make the infobox appear when pushpin is clicked for windows8 app XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-8, bing-maps

I'm new to Windows-8 apps and xaml, and I need help with bing maps.

I'm trying to develop a golfing app with a map that has pushpin that shows golf courses around the country. when a push-pin is clicked, an info box should appear with a little synopsis about that particular golf course and a link that will redirect the user to a page about that golf course.

Most of the examples I have found online use JavaScript which I cannot use since im working with XAML(desktop app).

Answer (score 1):

So handle the **Pushpin Click Event** and place navigation code inside:

```
this.frame.Navigate(typeof(PageClass),parameter);
```

Comment: The pushpin click event should display an info box for that pushpin, which i don't know how to do. Then the info box should navigate the user to the appropriate location when the link is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You should check [Bing Maps SDK for Windows Store apps](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb764f67-6b2c-4e14-b2d3-17477ae1eaca).